# Pure-JavaScript projects in NetBeans?

Tags: javascript, netbeans

I do a lot of JavaScript coding, and I really like NetBeans. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to create a "JavaScript" project in NetBeans. If I go to File -> New Project, my only options are "Java", "Ruby", and "NetBeans Modules". I don't want any of these. My project consists mostly of JavaScript, with a little bit of CSS.

I usually just end up creating a "Ruby" project, but this seems wrong, since I don't actually have any Ruby code. Why isn't there an option to create a "JavaScript" or "Web" project, or at least a "Generic" project that doesn't revolve around a specific language?

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Windows -> Favorites allows you to work out of arbitrary directories in NetBeans. You won't be able to "Run" your program or anything like that but you can edit files without having a Project.

Answer (score 3):

Sadly there's no option for a pure JavaScript project. Personally I use the PHP template as it seems adequate.

I suppose if you really want a proper project type, you have to [implement](http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-projecttype.html) it yourself.

Comment: I use the PHP module for this too, nice ability to use any arbitrary URL as the project URL too.

Answer (score 1):

**NetBeans 7.4** Released in October 2013, allows this functionality. As well as direct download of most major JS source files from CDNJS. Version 7.4 includes "Editing support for AngularJS, Knockout and ExtJS frameworks, Navigator and code folding in JSON files, Enhanced code completion with improved accuracy" see more here: https://netbeans.org/community/releases/74/

To set up a new JS project: under the File Menu choose -> New Project.

**Step 1:** Select HTML5 in categories and HTML5 Application in Projects
[image: Step 1: select HTML5 in categories and HTML5 Application in Projects]

**Step 2:** Name your application.
[image: Step 2: name your application]

**Step 3:** Choose a site template.
[image: Step 3: choose a site template]

**Step 4:** Search for available libraries, click on the Version number to download previous versions.
[image: Step 4: Search for available JS libraries in 'Available']

Finish and you are ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

Don't believe there is a Javascript project option. Netbeans just includes a Javascript editor.

Perhaps have a look at Eclipse and Aptana plugin.